# Dynamic placeholder in EE hides other existing placeholders

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, dynamic-placeholder

I have created a component that all it does is that it provides a `dynamic placeholder` to hold some other components, so it acts as a wrapper component.

Its variant has a `scriban template` that only displays my new dynamic placeholder key as follows.

[image]

The problem is that I open a page in `Experience Editor` and add my wrapper component, and then when I click on **Add new component**, the only placeholder that pops up now is my new dynamic placeholder, while other placeholders like the **main** placeholder doesn't show up.

[image]

Any idea why is the other placeholders on the page not showing up? and how can I make all placeholders available?

Comment: Where have you added your component with placeholder? Was it on partial design but any chance?

Comment: @Marek Musielak no, I directly added it on the page, not on a partial design.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the editable checbox is checked under the placeholder settings.

[image]

Hope this helps!